How to change GNOME Clock alarm sound (file)?
Till Ubuntu 22.04 I could just replace the /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.ogg with a new sound file (with the same name) and it worked.
But in Ubuntu 24.04 it does not work. The same beeping sound reappears although I even deleted the file (/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga – oga instead of ogg in the past).
Is there a new place and folder?
(I searched the internet and dconf-editor but could not find any hint for a new location or solution.)
